# no match for this type name warning with spring AOP & JBoss as 7

Tags: jboss7.x, spring-aop

I'm working on converting an app from AS 5 to AS 7 and have been able to make some progress, but am currently stumped.

When I attempt to start JBoss now, I'm getting an error from the AOP/Autowire annotation (when trying to create a bean):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: model.Sample [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301) [aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar:1.6.11]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:208) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getFallbackPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:359) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getShadowMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:410) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:273) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.MethodMatchers.matches(MethodMatchers.java:93) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.MethodMatchers$IntersectionMethodMatcher.matches(MethodMatchers.java:220) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:223) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
... 45 more
```

I've done a little bit of searching and found that adding:

```
<module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
```

to the jboss-deployment-structure.xml resolved some of those errors, but I am getting a different set now.  The original ones had to do with creating a datasource, these appear to have to do with the javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory (this is the only dependency the bean it is failing on has).

I'm at a loss of where to go to troubleshoot this and find out what library I am missing or what changes I need to make.  I'm guessing that like the with the other module that was required, I am missing a module that needs to be added, but can't figure out what it is.

Thanks.